# Repeatition of copying setup tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a customer has over 400 databases and creates new ones every week.  I use the export/import took to copy setup tables.  The problem is that the wizard is time consuming.  I have been trying to create a script to do this as the tables are always the same for every company.

```
USE HH885
TRUNCATE TABLE GL00100
GO
----Create new table and insert into table using SELECT INSERT
INSERT INTO HH885.dbo.GL00100
FROM HH001.dbo.GL00100
```

This gives me the message that the table already exists.

Comment: Is it sql server or mysql? What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you must be using the SELECT... INTO ... clause (despite the code snippet you have provided) which attempts to create a new table, but TRUNCATE does NOT delete (i.e. DROP) a table, it merely empties it. In other words change the TRUNCATE TABLE to DROP TABLE and then your script should work.

Answer (score 0):

if I drop the table it does not work because of how dynamics gp works.  I get errors.

Using this one I am making baby steps.  using the script below I get an error (Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'HH421.dbo.GL00100' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.)

use HH421
GO
truncate table gl00100
GO
insert into HH421.dbo.GL00100
select * from HH125.dbo.GL00100